# combobox windows phone 8.1 no dropdown

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I add a ComboBox in XAML for Windows Phone 8.1 in a StackPanel. On Running the app in the Emulator no Dropdown functionality is shown. If I Limit the StackPanel to a Height e.g. "70", only the 2 first Items are shown. If I say Height = "Auto" then all Items are shown immediately.

How can I enable the Dropdown functionality?

Header:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

Combobox ..

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PlayerListPanel" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select a Player" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBox Name="StartPlayerComboBox" BorderThickness="1" >
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="PLAYER1">Player 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="PLAYER2">Player 2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="PLAYER3">Player 3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="Dummy1">1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="Dummy2">2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="Dummy3">3</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  LISTPICKER  control..Its  functions  similar  as  ComboBox  with  Auto  adjusting height  and width..

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="A+" />
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="B+" />
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="O+" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

to  use this  Include following  namespace in  Xaml  Page..[ADD windows phone  toolkit(click  it)](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-install-windows-phone-toolkit---october-2012--8-0-sdk--via-nuget)

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

[image]

if   further  info  requires...  revert back...

Comment: My XAML Header Looks like this -see above-
I don't have the assembly Windows.phone.controls.toolkit

Comment: check  my  updated  answer..                                                                          please  add   reference  for  Windows.phone.controls.toolkit ...                 right click on reference  in  solution  explorer  ..add  new  reference..if  you  have  DLL on your  pc , refer it   otherwise   first  download  from   web   and  add  reference...     let  me know..  if  it  solved  select  as  an  answer,so  that  it  will be  helpful  for  young  developers..

Answer (score 0):

You should provide enough height for the `combobox` to open properly. If you limit the height, the `combobox` cannot extend beyond that. So it will show only a few items. Height = "Auto" means it can take whatever height as required by it. Thus the `combobox` will take the height required for it to open properly.

Answer (score 0):

Combobox is Windows Phone/ Windows RunTime Environment behaves differently from its Silverlight/WPF Counterparts.  Here we don't have Popup to show the List of items to be selected.  Hence the dropdown needs enough space to show the options.

Best thing is to leave the Height as Auto, or MinWidth for any Width requirements.

Comment: In other apps running on my Windows Phone the Combobox is initially shown with the default/selected value in the box and the other items hidden. If I then set the Focus on the control the box 'opens' and the other items are visible es well. How can I reach this 'open'-effect? In my example, using the "Auto"-height setting, the box shows initially all items not just the default/selected one.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho, this is an old question, in addition to what they have said, already; a way to have an item selected as the default, you need to "mark it" as follow:

```
<ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
```

Then, once you click on it, you will have all other combo box items displayed (if you define them):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" FontFamily="open sans" FontSize="20" Height="Auto" Foreground="DarkGray" BorderBrush="Black">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Hope it helps someone.  Regards